# How to print "<" and ">" using XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-sql

For example

I am creating an element with dynamic data -

```
XQUERY
let $sttag:=  concat('<', '/')
return concat ($sttag, "newTag")
```

above XQuery returns output as `&lt;/newTag` instead of `</newTag`.

it there any way to print "<" and ">" using xquery?

Answer (score 3):

**Here is an illustration of the most dynamic way to construct an element -- the name isn't known at compile time and is generally different at every execution**:

```
let $name := translate(concat('N', current-time()), ':','_')
  return
      element {$name} {}
```

**produces**:

```
<N21_26_40.708-07_00/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [XQuery's element constructors](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-constructors). You can create elements dynamically using a [computed element constructor](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-computedConstructors):

```
element book { 
    attribute isbn {"isbn-0060229357" }, 
    element title { "Harold and the Purple Crayon"},
    element author { 
        element first { "Crockett" }, 
        element last {"Johnson" }
    }
}
```

results in

```
<book isbn="isbn-0060229357">
    <title>Harold and the Purple Crayon</title>
    <author>
        <first>Crockett</first>
        <last>Johnson</last>
    </author>
</book>
```

(Example from the [W3C XQuery specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/))

In your case, you could use

```
element newTag { ... }
```

Comment: I'd just add that your `newTag` can also be dynamically constructed, e.g., `element { concat("new", "Tag") } { ... }`.

Comment: I'd also add that you could just put the XML elements right into the xQuery.  I find it to be more readable than the 'element {}' syntax.  I only use the 'element {}' syntax when I need to dynamically create an element.